# Create file .xls

Tags: java, excel

I want to create a file. Xls in Java, but I do not want him to be stored anywhere. I just want it to be created and is presented for download.

I have the following code, however after downloading the excel file says that a file is not valid.

```
private void criarFicheiroDeExemplo(RequestContext requestContext) throws IOException, InterruptedException {   
    requestContext.sResponse.setContentType("Excel.Application");
    requestContext.sResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename =Ficheiro_de_exemplo_incidencias.xls");

    java.io.PrintWriter pw = requestContext.sResponse.getWriter();

    String ficheiro = construirFormatoFicheiroDeExemplo();
    pw.println(ficheiro);

    pw.flush();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    pw.close();
}

private String construirFormatoFicheiroDeExemplo() {
    StringBuffer html = new StringBuffer();
    html.append("<table>"); //"Cria" a tabela
    html.append("<tr>");
    html.append("<td>");
    html.append("<Strong>ID_INCIDENCIA</Strong>");
    html.append("</td>");
    html.append("</tr>"); //"Cria" uma linha e uma coluna
    html.append("</table>");    
    return html.toString();
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does the error message say exactly? You may be running into the [extension hardening security features](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948615) in newer versions of Excel. Later versions of Excel now warn users when the file content does not match the file extension ie Like in your case the content is actually `html`, but your headers are "claiming" it is a binary Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Save the file to disk and open in a text editor to see if it contains what you expect. If it does, and Excel won't open it, then the problem isn't with the download process. The problem is with what's in the file.

If you don't want to mess around with generating Excel-format binary data, and you don't need anything like formulas in your spreadsheet, you can always get Excel to open TSV or CSV format (which is just plain text).